# Type Inference In swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to add a mutating method through Array extension. I'm creating a 2D array to do some calculations. But strangely Xcode is throwing me below error while creating 2D array

> error: cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type 'Int'.         var bucket : [[Int]] = Array.init(repeating: Int, count: base)

My playgound code is this ,

```
extension Array where Element == Int {

   public mutating func someTestMethod() {
    let base = 10
    var bucket : [[Int]] = Array.init(repeating: [Int](), count: base)
    // Some Other Code
     }
}
```

Where as the below code is working fine,

```
extension Array where Element == Int {

   public mutating func someTestMethod() {
    let base = 10
    var bucket : [[Int]] = .init(repeating: [Int](), count: base)
    // Some Other Code
    }
}
```

[image: Playground]

Would like know why is this happening since type inference should work in both cases. I would appreciate any help in understanding what is happening here.

Comment: I am not sure why the second one is fine but notice that the element is an [Int] so the where condition should be `where Element == [Int]`. _Actually when testing the code above the second method will also generate a compilation error when you try to use it so changing the `where` condition is the right solution here._

Comment: Element is just Int and not [Int] . So array type is [Int]. Inside this array i have an extension for sorting the integer values based on bucket sorting algorithm. Second method is not generating error for me as shown in screenshot i'm in Xcode 13.3.1 & on Mac 12.3.1. Sorry I don't get ur point. Could you explain a bit .

Comment: Yes bro I get you. Type of Array of [Int] is [[Int]] . My extension is for array of Integers. I'm trying to sort them using bucket sorting algorithm. For that i need an [[Int]] to put my elements. This is what the `var bucket` is for. I quite don't get why the first one doesn't work but second one works fine. Aren't both the code are same  . Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Second one works fine bro and bucket sorting algorithm is also woking as expected. My only question is why first one doesn't work and throws a compilation error ? i just want to understand what is happening behind the scene for both of these cases.

Comment: Yes sorry I had misunderstood the use case somewhat, `self` doesn't need to be a [[Int]] as I assumed.

Comment: Yes bro. Im not assigning bucket (`[[Int]]`) to self (`[Int]`) . Thank you for your efforts though. I really appreciate your time. Both declarations of `bucket` variable looks exactly same to me. But definitely they are not coz one is working and another isn't. So I'm just curious to know what is happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When omit the type for the init by only writing `.init`

```
var bucket : [[Int]] = .init(repeating: [Int](), count: base)
```

then the compiler deduces the init to call from the contextual type you have given, `var bucket : [[Int]]` so the complete init call is

```
Array<[Int]>.init(repeating: [Int](), count: base)
```

but if you use `Array.init` then the compiler uses the actual type of the extension which is given from the `where` condition to be  `Array<Int>`